# Nvidia graphics card is not being detected in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, nvidia, xorg, hp-pavilion

I updated my Ububtu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I have HP Pavilion 15ab 030tx. My nvidia graphics card is not being detected. Instead X.org was installed and is being used. What to do?

Comment: hi @Nikunj Gupta, apart from what @ Zacharee1 suggested above, have you tried doing this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers ??

Comment: X.org is going to be used no matter what since it's the display server interfacing between graphical applications in user-space and the graphics driver running in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Install 
`nvidia`
`nvidia-settings`

Reboot.

Here's some additional reference.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Edit -
On the chance that you have installed your drivers, but your card simply isn't being recognized, I'd make sure to be using Nvidia's drivers. Not Nouveau. Personally I've had issues in the past with my card not being recognized after installing Nouveau drivers, however, after purging the packages and installing the regular Nvidia drivers, I was able to move along just fine.